# LDAP configuration is not working for redmine

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ldap, redmine

We have a set of ubuntu machines which authenticate using LDAP. I have installed redmine application in one of the ubuntu machines and configured using the redmine ldap configuration. It seems to go well (based on 'test' ) see below:

Redmine LDAP page:
Authentication modes

Name    Type    Host    Users
ldap    LDAP    10.20.2.1   0   Test Delete

====

Yet, it is not able to login the LDAP users
I wanted to know how to make this work. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old. But, I will just say that I had to create the users first and select that they would use ldap authentication in order for them to sign in.

There is also a "On the fly user creation" setting that can be enabled, but it didn't seem to work for me.